# Comunication from activity to fragment

Tags: java, android, android-activity, fragment

I need go from a listview of one activity to one fragment when click in the image and textview of the listview.

I have a adapter:

```
public class AdapterResultList extends BaseAdapter {

    Context contexto;
    List<DirectoryData> ListaDirectorio;
    Fragment fragment = null;

    public AdapterResultList(Context contexto, List<DirectoryData> listaDirectorio) {
        this.contexto = contexto;
        ListaDirectorio = listaDirectorio;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View vista = convertView;
        LayoutInflater inflate = LayoutInflater.from(contexto);
        vista = inflate.inflate(R.layout.details_list_directory,null);

        TextView professionalName = (TextView) vista.findViewById(R.id.doctors_name);

        ImageView imagen1 = (ImageView) vista.findViewById(R.id.subcategory_image);               
        professionalName.setText(ListaDirectorio.get(position).getProfessionalName().toString());        
                           imagen1.setImageResource(ListaDirectorio.get(position).getImagen1());


        return vista;
    }
}
```

And in the activity:

```
public class ResultSearch extends AppCompatActivity {
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_result_search);

    listaProf = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_profesionals);

            ListaDr = new ArrayList<DirectoryData>();
            ListaDr.add(new DirectoryData("Dr. Pedro Perez", R.drawable.successright));
            ListaDr.add(new DirectoryData("Dr. Juan Rodriguez", R.drawable.searchbanner));

            AdapterResultList miadaptador = new AdapterResultList(getApplicationContext(), ListaDr);
            listaProf.setAdapter(miadaptador);
    }
}
```

When click in the imageview or textview I need only go to `DoctorsDetailsFragment`. I don't need to send data.

Comment: use click listener in adapter and call the fragment from adaptor

Comment: Yes i think that, but how call the fragment from adapter?. Excuse me im new in this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass arguments to Fragment by using `setArguments`. Use the following method

```
Fragment fragment = new StaticContent();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("Key", "Value");
fragment.setArguments(bundle);
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).addToBackStack(null).commitAllowingStateLoss();
fragmentManager.executePendingTransactions();
```

Comment: I just need to go from activity to fragment, as with an Intent-starActivity between activities, but from an activity to a fragment.

Answer (score 0):

1.`Override OnDataBind` method of adapter and inside that use `onClickListener` of `TextView` or image....search and you will get plenty of code.

2.From `activity` to `fragment` ....just use another dummy `activity` inside which the actual `fragment` will load.

Start as usual when you call an `activity` from another.